# Python Variable Mutation Best Practice

Tags: python, string

Let's say I'm passing a variable into a function, and I want to ensure it's properly formatted for my end use, with consideration for several potential unwanted formats.

Example; I want to store only lowercase representations of url addresses, without http:// or https://.

```
def standardize(url):
    # Lowercase
    temp_url = url
    url = temp_url.lower()

    # Remove 'http://'
    if 'http://' in url:
        temp_url = url
        url = temp_url.replace('http://', '')

    if 'https://' in url:
        temp_url = url
        url = temp_url.replace('https://', '')

    return url
```

I'm only just encroaching on the title of Novice, and was wondering if there is more pythonic approach to achieving this type of process?

End goal being the trasformation of a url as such `https://myurl.com/RANDoM` --> `myurl.com/random`

The application of url string formating isn't of any particular importance.

Comment: You don't need `temp_url`. Other than that, this seems pretty typical.

Comment: so just `url.lower()` rather than `url = temp_url.lower()`?

Comment: You still need to assign it back to `url`, so `url = url.lower()` But I'm not exactly sure what your question is... can you describe specifically what you are wondering about?

Comment: That answered it, I was just really confused about a simple nuance I think.

Comment: Read this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def standardize(url):
    return url.lower().replace("https://","").replace("http://","")
```

That's as simple as I can make it, but, the chaining is a little ugly.

If you want to import regex, could also do something like this:

```
import re

def standardize(url):
    return re.sub("^https?://", "", url.lower())
```

Comment: That's what I was wondering, for sure. I was a bit confused on how directly  one is able to format a variable I think.

Comment: @Darkstarone Now that's exactly copying my answer (the regex part).... and you know that's not allowed:(

Comment: It was the non-regex answer that was of interest to me

Comment: @abccd, I had a different regex initially (`"https?:\/{2}"`), but refactored it before submitting, didn't see your answer until after submit.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `re.sub` will do the trick:

```
import re
def standardize(url):
     return re.sub("^https?://",'',url.lower())

# with 'https'
print(standardize('https://myurl.com/RANDoM')) # prints 'myurl.com/random'
# with 'http'
print(standardize('http://myurl.com/RANDoM')) # prints 'myurl.com/random'
# both works
```